# Pound symbol (£) length or charset problem in Zend form ?

Tags: php, zend-framework, character-encoding, passwords, zend-form

my password field (Zend Form) is allowing string length 6,20

but When I type "guru£"(string lenth 5:fasle) it is returning true without minlenth error and same time if I type "guru££££" (string length: true) it is return max lenth error.

can any one help me out regrading this one. and Thanks in advance-Guru

Comment: £ is a multibyte character, so will register as two characters in php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be using some multibyte character encoding, probably UTF-8. You must explicitly tell this to Zend_Validate so that it works correctly:

```
$validator->setEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Or you can do it while creating validator object:

```
$validator = new Zend_Validate_StringLength(
    array('min' => 6, 'max' => 20, 'encoding' => 'UTF-8')
);
```

See [Zend_Validate > Encoding of values](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.set.stringlength.encoding) in Zend Framework manual.

Comment: thank you very much crack. You saved lot of my time and effort. You got a excellent zend framework skills.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Zend Validation class?

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.set.html

Of particular note is the Using different languages section, I think.